# Module containing insertUI and removeUI in a Shiny App not reacting to Action Buttons

Tags: r, image, shiny, module, reactive

### BUILDING MODULE OF IMAGE GALLERY

I just learned about Shiny modules and have been reading about it for hours.
However, I can't seem to figure out how to get an insertUI and removeUI to work in conjunction with a module and action buttons.

Here is what I'm struggling with:

I have 2 action buttons on the UI; one that triggers an insertUI from a module and the other that triggers a removeUI. The latter is meant to remove those UIs that were inserted.

The user would click the "Add" button and a gallery button appears, which, when hit, displays some images.

The user can click on any image in that gallery in order to select it.

The image selection triggers a renderText that will show the name of the image.

The problem: the "Remove" button does not work inside the Module and I'm not sure why.
Some of the code came from this excellent tutorial: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/02/shiny-add-removing-modules-dynamically/.

Here is the fully code. Any guidance would be really appreciated!

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(stringr)
library(shinyanimate)
library(shinyjqui)

# Creating the Dataframe
datafofimages <- data.frame(Finance = c('Slide1.jpg', 'Slide2.jpg', 'Slide3.jpg', 'Slide4.jpg','Slide5.jpg', 'Slide6.jpg'),
                            Product = c('Slide2.jpg', 'Slide1.jpg', 'Slide3.jpg', 'Slide4.jpg','Slide5.jpg', 'Slide6.jpg'),
                            Customers = c('Slide3.jpg', 'Slide4.jpg', 'Slide1.jpg', 'Slide2.jpg','Slide5.jpg', 'Slide6.jpg'), 
                            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Creating the Module UI
innerModUI <- function(id) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)

      
    dropMenu(placement = 'right',
             
             actionButton(
               inputId = ns("mydropdown1"),
               label = "Gallery of Slides",
               icon = icon("images")),
             
             br(),
             fluidRow(
               column(9,
                      column(3,
                             uiOutput(ns("picker"))),
                      column(3,
                             useShinyjs(),
                             textOutput(ns("dynamic"))),
                      column(3,
                             uiOutput(ns("remove"))))),
             
             fluidRow(
               column(10,
                      panel(style="background: #2e7c9e; width:100%; height:100%; margin:float-center;",
                            column(6, align = 'center',
                                   uiOutput(ns('img1'), style="cursor:pointer; margin-bottom:65px; margin-top:15px; align:center"),
                                   uiOutput(ns('img2'), style="cursor:pointer; margin-bottom:65px; margin-top:15px; align:center"),
                                   uiOutput(ns('img3'), style="cursor:pointer; margin-bottom:65px; margin-top:15px; align:center")),
                            column(6, align = 'center',
                                   uiOutput(ns('img4'), style="cursor:pointer; margin-bottom:65px; margin-top:15px; align:center"),
                                   uiOutput(ns('img5'), style="cursor:pointer; margin-bottom:65px; margin-top:15px; align:center"),
                                   uiOutput(ns('img6'), style="cursor:pointer; margin-bottom:65px; margin-top:15px; align:center")))))  
             
             )}

innerMod <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ns <- session$ns
  
  tagList(
    
    output$picker <- renderUI({
      ns <- session$ns
      pickerInput(ns('selection') , choices = c('Finance', 'Product', 'Customers'))}),
    
    observeEvent(input$selection, {

    selectioned <- datafofimages %>% select(input$selection)
      
      output$img1 <- renderUI({
        ns <- session$ns
        tags$img(id = ns('firstImage'),
                 src = paste0(selectioned[1,1]),
                 width = "90%", height = "100%") }) 
      
      output$img2 <- renderUI({
        ns <- session$ns
        tags$img(id = ns('secondImage'),
                 src = paste0(selectioned[2,1]),
                 width = "90%", height = "100%")})
      
      output$img3 <- renderUI({
        ns <- session$ns
        tags$img(id = ns('thirdImage'),
                 src = paste0(selectioned[3,1]),
                 width = "90%", height = "100%")})
      
      output$img4 <- renderUI({
        ns <- session$ns
        tags$img(id = ns('fourthImage'),
           src = paste0(selectioned[4,1]),
           width = "90%", height = "100%")}) 
      
      output$img5 <- renderUI({
        ns <- session$ns
        tags$img(id = ns('fifthImage'),
                 src = paste0(selectioned[5,1]),
                 width = "90%", height = "100%")}) 
      
      output$img6 <- renderUI({
        ns <- session$ns
        tags$img(id = ns('sixthImage'),
                 src = paste0(selectioned[6,1]),
                 width = "90%", height = "100%")})
      
      output$dynamic <- renderText({
        req(input$selection)
        to_print <- paste0(unlist(str_remove_all(image_name(), '.jpg')))
        return(to_print)})
      })) 
  
  image_name <- reactiveVal()
  shinyjs::onclick("img1",  image_name(paste0(input$selection, ' ', 'Slide1.jpg')))
  shinyjs::onclick("img2",  image_name(paste0(input$selection, ' ', 'Slide2.jpg')))
  shinyjs::onclick("img3",  image_name(paste0(input$selection, ' ', 'Slide3.jpg')))
  shinyjs::onclick("img4",  image_name(paste0(input$selection, ' ', 'Slide4.jpg')))
  shinyjs::onclick("img5",  image_name(paste0(input$selection, ' ', 'Slide5.jpg')))
  shinyjs::onclick("img6",  image_name(paste0(input$selection, ' ', 'Slide6.jpg'))) }


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  fluidRow(
    column(12,
      actionButton("add_com",
                     style='padding:4px; font-size:80%;',
                     label = "Add", 
                     style = "fill",
                     color = "primary",
                     icon = icon("comment"),
                     size = "sm"),
        
        actionButton("rm_com",
                     style='padding:4px; font-size:80%;',
                     label = "Remove",
                     style = "fill",
                     color = "success",
                     icon = icon("comment-slash"),
                     size = "sm"))))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$add_com, {
    
    i <- sprintf('%04d', input$add_com)
    id <- sprintf('lmModel%s', i)
    
    insertUI(
      selector = '#add_com',
      where = "beforeBegin",
      ui = innerModUI(id))

    callModule(innerMod, id)
    
    remove_shiny_inputs <- function(id, .input) {
      invisible(
        lapply(grep(id, names(.input), value = TRUE), function(i) {
          .subset2(.input, "impl")$.values$remove(i)
        })
      )}
    
    observeEvent(input[[paste0(id, '-rm_com')]], {
      removeUI(selector = sprintf('#%s', id))
      remove_shiny_inputs(id, input)})}) }
  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested (no reproducible example), but as far as I can tell the problem is that you don't create a removal button within the module, only in the main `ui` function.

Try this (though I haven't tested it):

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(stringr)
library(shinyanimate)
library(shinyjqui)

# Creating the Dataframe
datafofimages <- data.frame(Finance = c('Slide1.jpg', 'Slide2.jpg', 'Slide3.jpg', 'Slide4.jpg','Slide5.jpg', 'Slide6.jpg'),
                            Product = c('Slide2.jpg', 'Slide1.jpg', 'Slide3.jpg', 'Slide4.jpg','Slide5.jpg', 'Slide6.jpg'),
                            Customers = c('Slide3.jpg', 'Slide4.jpg', 'Slide1.jpg', 'Slide2.jpg','Slide5.jpg', 'Slide6.jpg'), 
                            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# creating helper function
remove_shiny_inputs <- function(id, .input) {
  invisible(
    lapply(grep(id, names(.input), value = TRUE), function(i) {
      .subset2(.input, "impl")$.values$remove(i)
    })
  )}

# Creating the Module UI
innerModUI <- function(id) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  
  dropMenu(placement = 'right',
           
           actionButton(
             inputId = ns("mydropdown1"),
             label = "Gallery of Slides",
             icon = icon("images")),
           
           br(),
           fluidRow(
             column(9,
                    column(3,
                           uiOutput(ns("picker"))),
                    column(3,
                           useShinyjs(),
                           textOutput(ns("dynamic"))),
                    column(3,
                           actionButton(ns("rm_com"),
                                        style='padding:4px; font-size:80%;',
                                        label = "Remove",
                                        style = "fill",
                                        color = "success",
                                        icon = icon("comment-slash"),
                                        size = "sm")))),
           
           fluidRow(
             column(10,
                    panel(style="background: #2e7c9e; width:100%; height:100%; margin:float-center;",
                          column(6, align = 'center',
                                 uiOutput(ns('img1'), style="cursor:pointer; margin-bottom:65px; margin-top:15px; align:center"),
                                 uiOutput(ns('img2'), style="cursor:pointer; margin-bottom:65px; margin-top:15px; align:center"),
                                 uiOutput(ns('img3'), style="cursor:pointer; margin-bottom:65px; margin-top:15px; align:center")),
                          column(6, align = 'center',
                                 uiOutput(ns('img4'), style="cursor:pointer; margin-bottom:65px; margin-top:15px; align:center"),
                                 uiOutput(ns('img5'), style="cursor:pointer; margin-bottom:65px; margin-top:15px; align:center"),
                                 uiOutput(ns('img6'), style="cursor:pointer; margin-bottom:65px; margin-top:15px; align:center")))))  
           
  )}

innerMod <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ns <- session$ns
    
    output$picker <- renderUI({
      ns <- session$ns
      pickerInput(ns('selection') , choices = c('Finance', 'Product', 'Customers'))})
    
    observeEvent(input$selection, {
      
      output$img1 <- renderUI({
        ns <- session$ns
        tags$img(id = ns('firstImage'),
                 src = paste0(selectioned[1,1]),
                 width = "90%", height = "100%") }) 
      
      output$img2 <- renderUI({
        ns <- session$ns
        tags$img(id = ns('secondImage'),
                 src = paste0(selectioned[2,1]),
                 width = "90%", height = "100%")})
      
      output$img3 <- renderUI({
        ns <- session$ns
        tags$img(id = ns('thirdImage'),
                 src = paste0(selectioned[3,1]),
                 width = "90%", height = "100%")})
      
      output$img4 <- renderUI({
        ns <- session$ns
        tags$img(id = ns('fourthImage'),
                 src = paste0(selectioned[4,1]),
                 width = "90%", height = "100%")}) 
      
      output$img5 <- renderUI({
        ns <- session$ns
        tags$img(id = ns('fifthImage'),
                 src = paste0(selectioned[5,1]),
                 width = "90%", height = "100%")}) 
      
      output$img6 <- renderUI({
        ns <- session$ns
        tags$img(id = ns('sixthImage'),
                 src = paste0(selectioned[6,1]),
                 width = "90%", height = "100%")})
      
      output$dynamic <- renderText({
        req(input$selection)
        to_print <- paste0(unlist(str_remove_all(image_name(), '.jpg')))
        return(to_print)})
    }) 
  
  image_name <- reactiveVal()
  shinyjs::onclick("img1",  image_name(paste0(input$selection, ' ', 'Slide1.jpg')))
  shinyjs::onclick("img2",  image_name(paste0(input$selection, ' ', 'Slide2.jpg')))
  shinyjs::onclick("img3",  image_name(paste0(input$selection, ' ', 'Slide3.jpg')))
  shinyjs::onclick("img4",  image_name(paste0(input$selection, ' ', 'Slide4.jpg')))
  shinyjs::onclick("img5",  image_name(paste0(input$selection, ' ', 'Slide5.jpg')))
  shinyjs::onclick("img6",  image_name(paste0(input$selection, ' ', 'Slide6.jpg'))) }


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  fluidRow(
    column(12,
           actionButton("add_com",
                        style='padding:4px; font-size:80%;',
                        label = "Add", 
                        style = "fill",
                        color = "primary",
                        icon = icon("comment"),
                        size = "sm"))))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$add_com, {
    
    i <- sprintf('%04d', input$add_com)
    id <- sprintf('lmModel%s', i)
    
    insertUI(
      selector = '#add_com',
      where = "beforeBegin",
      ui = innerModUI(id))
    
    callModule(innerMod, id)
    
    observeEvent(input[[paste0(id, '-rm_com')]], {
      removeUI(selector = sprintf('#%s', id))
      remove_shiny_inputs(id, input)})}) }


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

- I've also removed a `tagList` you shouldn't need in the `server` function
- initialised the helper function `remove_shiny_inputs` at the beginning and not every time you insert a new module

Comment: Thank you very much, @starja. I added a line of code I failed to include earlier, which has to do with the pickerInput:                                                                         
`selectioned <- datafofimages %>% select(input$selection)`. The images live in the "www" as .jpg. I ran your suggested code, but sadly couldn't get it to work as intended. I would need the Remove button to be next to the Add button on the main UI. I wonder if there is a way to remove those inserted UIs with that Remove button